# Serial comms not reaching 0 V

Tags: arduino, sensor, serial, esp8266

Connecting a DHT22 sensor to an ESP8266, I can't read the serial data sent back from the sensor.

I'm almost sure this is a problem with the sensor communication not reaching 0 V as the software always reads a logic 1 on the pin. If I connect it to GND, it does read a logic 0 so it's not a port problem.

How can I make it reach 0 V? Where is this offset voltage coming from?

[image]

PD: This doesn't work with any DHT22 library for Arduino, nor with my FreeRTOS code.

PDD: I've tried using an external 10K pull-up and the internal pull-up from the ESP8266.

EDIT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRr6pa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you share the circuit, how you are connecting the sensor?

Comment: Check input voltage at pin 1 and 4 of the DHT22 sensor. how much is it?

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add a schematic. The schematic editor here is a breeze to use.

Comment: Voltage between pins 1 and 4 is 3.28V

Comment: Double check the wiring for mixups or missing connections.

Comment: Already done, actually this was ariginally in a shield for the esp8266 but I unsoldered the sensor wired it in a protoboard